# Last piece of the puzzle is to change this function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have to change this function using a pointer instead of `int i` and I have problems because my instinct tells me to use a `char` pointer and every time to increase the pointer to the next string but I don't know how to implement that.

This is what I have so far:

```
populate_demo()

{
    int i;
    for (i=0; evalue[i][0] ; i++)
        env_add("DEMO",evalue[i]);
}
```

I've been experimenting of course it is not like I did not try but I cant seem to accomplish what I need here is my code

```
int main()
{
char array1[4][6]={"one","two","three","four"};
char *p;
p=array1[0];
*p++;
printf("%s",p);
return 0;
}
```

Expected result: `printf` prints "two". but instead goes to the next char of the first string and prints ne until it finds `\0`. So my question is how to go to the next string?

Comment: Perhaps re-read the chapter on pointers

Comment: If it's a pointer to a char*, you should be able to just increment it.

Comment: @Justanewb  Show how evalue is declared.

Comment: First and foremost, your function is not legal C as is. You cannot omit function return type. Perhaps you are using outdated learning resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array like this

```
char array1[4][6]={"one","two","three","four"};
```

then pointer to its first element will look like

```
char ( *p )[6] = array1;
```

Thus you can write for example

```
printf( "%s", *p );
```

or

```
printf( "%s", *++p );
```

or

```
printf( "%s", *p++ );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   6

void populate_demo( char evalue[][N] )
{
    for ( ; ( *evalue )[0]; ++evalue ) puts( *evalue );
}    

int main( void )
{
    char array1[][N] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "" };

    populate_demo( array1 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
one
two
three
four
```

If the array does not contain an empty string then the program above can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   6

void populate_demo( char evalue[][N], size_t n )
{
    for ( char ( *p )[N] = evalue; p != evalue + n; ++p ) puts( *p );
}    

int main( void )
{
    char array1[][N] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

    populate_demo( array1, sizeof( array1 ) / sizeof( *array1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same.

If the compiler supports variable size array you can use them also as function parameters.